# Открыть localhost visual studio для mac os в виртуалке

Tags: visual-studio, macos, отладка, virtualbox, localhost

Основная суть в самом вопросе.
Есть проект в visual studio, который открывается как localhost:порт по обычному F5 .
Так же есть виртуалка(VirtualBox) MacOs , через которую и нужно смотреть на этот локалхост.
Это реально?

Comment: да, реально, создаете сеть между хостом и виртуалкой (тогда у хоста появится адрес, который будет доступен внутри виртуалки), и поднимаете ваш проект на *:порт

Comment: К сожалению, без порта, показывает просто приветствие IIS, а с портом, просто не отображает страницу